# Binary search tree search operation time complexity graph looks more like O(1) than O(log N)

Tags: python, c++, algorithm, time-complexity, binary-search-tree

I have an assignment where I need to plot the measured time of sorting algorithms and compare the data points to the theoretical curve. For a long time I've been having an issue with binary search tree's search operation - the curve does not look correct based on my data.

The time complexity for a balanced binary search tree is O(log N), however, my data suggests something more akin to O(1), which is definitely wrong. I use C++ to implement the BST as well as to test it in an AlgoTest class.

From C++ I write the data in a readable format to a text file, then I use python for plotting the graph using that data by parsing the file. The format of the file is:

```
N   T/S[ns] Stdev[ns]   Samples
100 61.7918 3.72863     50
200 61.3857 4.60256     50
300 60.3103 0.99732     50
400 61.2175 1.43153     50
500 59.2468 1.99970     50
600 50.6475 3.92420     50
700 49.9104 2.11822     50
800 50.1703 2.12117     50
900 55.1898 5.09409     50
```

In my original project, I of course split the code up in a sensible way between different translation units, but for the purpose of being easy to copy and test yourself, I put all the code in the same file. Here's the C++ code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <valarray>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <optional>
#include <stack>
#include <iostream>

/********************************BST CLASS**************************************/
struct node {
    node() = default;
    explicit node(const int& val) : data(val), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
    int data;
    node* left;
    node* right;
};

class BinarySearchTree {
public:
    explicit BinarySearchTree(const auto& primes) : root(nullptr) {
        root = constructBST(primes, 0, primes.size() - 1);
    }
    std::optional<node*> search(int& val) {
        return search_iterative(val, root);
    }
    void print() { inorderTraversal(root); }
private:
    node* root;

    node* constructBST(const std::vector<int>& nums, int start, int end){
        if (start > end) return nullptr;
        int mid = (start + end) / 2;
        node* root_ = new node(nums[mid]);
        root_->left = constructBST(nums, start, mid - 1);
        root_->right = constructBST(nums, mid + 1, end);
        return root_;
    }
    std::optional<node*> search_iterative(int val, node*& vertex) {
        while (vertex) {
            if (val == vertex->data) return vertex;
            else if (val < vertex->data) vertex = vertex->left;
            else vertex = vertex->right;
        } return std::nullopt;
    }
    static void inorderTraversal(node*& root_) {
        std::stack<node*> stack;    // Create an empty stack.
        // If the current node is null and stack is also empty, the algorithm terminates.
        while (!stack.empty() || root_) {
            // Push the current node to the stack and set current=current->left.
            if (root_ != nullptr) {
                stack.push(root_);
                root_ = root_->left;
            }
            else {  // If the curr node is NULL.
                root_ = stack.top();
                stack.pop(); // Pop the node on top of stack.
                std::cout << root_->data << ", "; // Print it.
                root_ = root_->right;
            }
        }
    }
};

/************************ SIEVE OF ERATOSTHENES IMPLEMENTATION ************************/
// for finding prime numbers
void findPrimes(std::vector<bool>& v) {
    const size_t N = v.size();
    v[0] = false;     // 0 is not a prime number
    v[1] = false;     // 1 is not a prime number
    int i = 2;
    while (i < N/2) {
        int divisor = i * 2;
        while (divisor < N) { v[divisor] = false; divisor += i; }
        i += 1; while (!v[i]) { i += 1; }
    }
}

/********************************* TIMER CLASS ***********************************/
using std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
using std::chrono::duration_cast;
using std::chrono::duration;
using std::chrono::milliseconds;

class Timer {
public:
    explicit Timer(const double& search_period) :
            time_period(search_period), start_time(0), stop_time(0) {}
    void start() { start_time = high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch(); }
    void stop() { stop_time = high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch(); }
    const double& search_period() { return time_period; }
    [[nodiscard]] double elapsedTime() {
        stop();
        double elapsed = stop_time.count() - start_time.count();
        return elapsed;
    }
private:
    duration<double, std::nano> start_time;
    duration<double, std::nano> stop_time;
    const double time_period;
};

/****************** GENERATE RANDOM PRIME NUMBER *************************/
int random_prime_number(auto first, auto last) {
    std::vector<int> out;
    std::sample( first, last, std::back_inserter(out),
                 1,  // one random element is chosen
                 std::mt19937{std::random_device{}()}
    );
    return *out.begin();
}

/***************** GET STANDARD DEVIATION ******************/
double standardDeviation(const std::vector<double>& data_points, const double& mean_val) {
    auto N = static_cast<double>(data_points.size());
    double square_sum = 0;
    for (auto& sample_val : data_points)
    { square_sum += std::pow(sample_val - mean_val, 2); }
    double factor = (1 / (N - 1));
    return std::sqrt(factor * square_sum);
}

/***************************** CLASS FOR TESTING THE ALGORITHM *************************************/
class AlgoTest {
public:
    // constructor
    AlgoTest(const std::string& outputFileName, const size_t& elements_start_size,
             const size_t& interval, const Timer& t) : output_file(outputFileName),
             x_measurement_point(elements_start_size), x_interval(interval),
             X_LIM_FACTOR(20), NUM_OF_SAMPLES(50), x_lim((x_interval*X_LIM_FACTOR)+elements_start_size),
             measurements(0), timer(t) {}
    // find out what the primes are
    std::vector<bool> identifyPrimes() const {
        auto primes_limit = (size_t)std::pow(x_measurement_point, 2);
        std::vector<bool> prime(primes_limit, true);
        findPrimes(prime);
        return prime;
    }
    // Initialize measurement operations
    void makeMeasurements() {
        // write header to file for readability
        output_file << "N\t" << "T/S[ns]\t" << "Stdev[ns]\t" << "Samples\n";
        // for each x (for each input size), we generate that many prime numbers
        while (x_measurement_point != x_lim) {
            std::vector<bool> prime = identifyPrimes();
            prime_numbers.clear();
            for (int num = 2; num < prime.size(); ++num) {
                if (prime[num]) {
                    prime_numbers.push_back(num);
                    if (prime_numbers.size() == x_measurement_point) break;
                }
            }
            // clear previous measurements and collect samples
            measurements.clear(); collectSamples();
            // calculate the sum and standard deviation
            calculateMeasurementsData();
            // go to the next input size
            x_measurement_point += x_interval;
        }
        output_file << "-" << "\n";     // indicates that it's finished
    }
private:
    void collectSamples() {
        // 50 samples (measurements) for each input size for the search algorithm
        for (int k = 0; k < NUM_OF_SAMPLES; ++k) {
            // generate a new random number to search upon each iteration
            int rand_prime = random_prime_number(std::begin(prime_numbers), std::end(prime_numbers));
            // construct a new balanced binary search tree upon each iteration
            BinarySearchTree bst(prime_numbers);
            // initialize data
            size_t numOfSearches = 0;
            double elapsed = 0.0;
            const double searchPeriod = timer.search_period();
            // start the timer
            timer.start();
            while (elapsed < searchPeriod) {
                bst.search(rand_prime);
                ++numOfSearches;
                elapsed = timer.elapsedTime();
            }
            /* From the measurements we calculate the time period (1ms = 1'000'000ns) divided by
             * the number of searches made during that time. This gives us a ratio indicating
             * the average time it took to complete one search during the time period. */
            auto avg_search_time = timer.search_period() / (double)numOfSearches;
            measurements.push_back(avg_search_time);
        }
    }
    // get sum, standard deviation
    void calculateMeasurementsData() {
        double sum = std::accumulate(measurements.begin(), measurements.end(), 0.0);
        double avg = sum / NUM_OF_SAMPLES;
        double stand_dev = standardDeviation(measurements, avg);
        saveMeasurements(x_measurement_point, avg,stand_dev);
    }
    // write data to file
    void saveMeasurements(const size_t& numOfElements, const double& ratio, const double& std_dev) {
        int decimal_place = (int)std::to_string(ratio).find('.');
        int delim = decimal_place + 5;
        std::string r = std::to_string(ratio).substr(0, delim);
        std::string dev = std::to_string(std_dev).substr(0, delim);
        output_file << numOfElements << "\t" << r << "\t" << dev << "\t"
                    << std::to_string(NUM_OF_SAMPLES) << "\n";
    }
protected:
    std::ofstream output_file;
    size_t x_measurement_point;
    size_t x_interval;
    const uint8_t X_LIM_FACTOR, NUM_OF_SAMPLES;
    size_t x_lim;
    std::vector<double> measurements;
    std::vector<int> prime_numbers;
    Timer timer;
};

const std::string filename1 = R"(C:\tmp\bst_search.txt)";

int main() {

    AlgoTest
    // output filename, start input size, interval, Timer with search period 1'000'000 ns = 1 ms
    at(filename1, 1'000, 1'000, Timer(1'000'000));

    at.makeMeasurements();

    return 0;
}
```

**For clarification**: we are to use the input of increasing prime numbers. You pass the starting input size in the AlgoTest constructor, and set the desired interval. For each input size, I get X amount of samples (in this case 50), to properly calculate the standard deviation.

The actual time measurement (T/S) involves a predefined search period (in this case 1'000'000 ns = 1 ms), divided by the amount of searches made during the time period. This is the method our teacher wants us to follow, since trying to do a simple start and stop with a timer isn't going to work with nanoseconds.

The following is the python code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.lines as mlines
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# ------------------- PARSE ALGORITHM DATA FROM FILE CLASS --------------------
class AlgoData:
    def __init__(self, algo_name):
        self.algo = algo_name
        self.getData()

    def getData(self):  # parses the file
        data = open("C:\\tmp\\bst_search.txt", 'r')
        with data as file:
            lines = [line.rstrip() for line in file]
        for line in lines[1:]:
            if '-' in line: break
            self.addX(float(line.split('\t')[0]))
            self.addY(float(line.split('\t')[1]))
            self.addDev(float(line.split('\t')[2]))

    def name(self): return self.algo

    def N_elements_list(self): return self.x_data
    def avg_time_list(self): return self.y_data
    def std_dev_list(self): return self.std_dev

    def addX(self, x): self.x_data.append(x)
    def addY(self, y): self.y_data.append(y)
    def addDev(self, dev): self.std_dev.append(dev)

    x_data = []
    y_data = []
    std_dev = []
    algo = ""
    x_start = 0
    x_lim = 0


# ----------------------------- PLOT CLASS ----------------------------
def logarithmic(N, k):
    return k * np.log2(N)


class Plot:
    def __init__(self, x_data, y_data, std_dev):
        self.plot_header = "Binary serach tree"
        self.x_axis_name = "N elements"
        self.y_axis_name = "T/S[ns]"
        self.x_data = x_data
        self.y_data = y_data
        self.x_start = self.x_data[0]
        self.x_end = self.x_data[-1]
        self.std_dev = std_dev
        self.fn_label = "Fit k O(log N)"
        self.algo_fn_ptr = logarithmic
        self.setPlotValues(self)

    @staticmethod
    def setPlotValues(self):
        # Fit the function to the data using non-linear regression
        # returns optimal parameters such that we get the curve that
        # best fits the specified function to our dataset
        # popt - optimal parameters, pcov - parameter covariance
        params, _ = curve_fit(logarithmic, self.x_data, self.y_data)
        x_fit = np.linspace(0, self.x_end, 1000)
        plt.xlim(0, self.x_end)
        plt.ylim(0, self.y_data[-1] * 2)
        plt.plot(x_fit, logarithmic(x_fit, *params), label=self.fn_label, color='g')

    def showPlot(self):
        plt.title(self.plot_header)
        plt.xlabel(self.x_axis_name)
        plt.ylabel(self.y_axis_name)
        plt.plot(self.x_data, self.y_data, 'o',
                 label='Increasing prime numbers', color='purple', linestyle='None')
        plt.errorbar(self.x_data, self.y_data, ecolor='purple', fmt='-',
                     yerr=self.std_dev, capsize=3, linestyle='None')

        fn_curve = mlines.Line2D([], [], color='green', markersize=8, label=self.fn_label)
        experimental_data = mlines.Line2D([], [], color='purple', markersize=8, label="Increasing prime numbers")
        plt.legend(handles=[fn_curve, experimental_data])
        plt.show()

    x_axis_name = ""
    y_axis_name = ""
    plot_header = ""
    x_data = []
    y_data = []
    std_dev = []
    fn_label = ""
    x_start = 0
    x_end = 0

ad = AlgoData("Binary search tree")


plt_ = Plot(ad.N_elements_list(), ad.avg_time_list(), ad.std_dev_list())
plt_.showPlot()
```

**What I have tried**

- Checked that the sum and standard deviation is working correctly
- Made sure that the BST actually searches for a value and finds it.
- Made sure that the BST is balanced and that the root node is the middle one, and inspecting the left and right nodes to be correct
- Tried to use `volatile` keyword to prevent compiler optimization
- Tried to use the results (numOfSearches, search function return value) and push them to a vector in a different translation unit - again, to prevent compiler optimizations
- Tried to run both in debug and release mode. This has had an effect on linear search algorithm, but not so much here.
- Made sure that the prime numbers are generated correctly for each iteration
- Tried to find errors in the timer.
- Made sure that the python file parser reads the data correctly
- Tried different input sizes, intervals and search periods

Finally, the current (wrong) graph looks like this:
[image]

With all that said, I understand if you don't have the time to look deeply into all of this code, but I would appreciate it if anyone at least could take a quick glance and tell me if they see something that might cause the problem.

Even with all the things I've tried and tested, it's possible I might have implemented the BST wrong somewhere, or maybe the timer class isn't correct?

I think that the problem may be either compiler optimizations, incorrect BST implementation, or the way I measure is wrong.

So really my question is, can you see anything that's clearly wrong in my implementation somewhere that might be the culprit? I appreciate any feedback.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253731/discussion-on-question-by-proxylite-binary-search-tree-search-operation-time-com); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Since you passed a `node*&` to `search_iterative()` instead of a `node*`, each search overwrites the member `root` with the last node traversed, which presumably explains why the measurements are constant.